# Is there an intuitive picture for quasi-isodynamic versus quasi-axisymmetric versus quasi-helically symmetric flow in stellarators?

Tags: coordinate-systems, plasma-physics, fusion

I recently read a [paper](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1741-4326/ac170f/meta) in which Alan Boozer says,

> The W7-X stellarator was made quasi-isodynamic rather than
> quasi-symmetric in order to minimize the parallel currents as well as
> the ripple-trapped diffusion.

Page 2 of a separate [article](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/journal-of-plasma-physics/article/singlefieldperiod-quasiisodynamic-stellarator/9B2A5FDCCD7774E4F91BE45E75FDC6B0) by Jorge and coauthors gives an explanation of the concepts of quasi-symmetric and quasi-isodynamic and the related concept of quasi-helically symmetric:

> There are currently three types of optimized stellarator
> configurations that appear to have the potential to become future
> fusion reactors: (1) quasi-isodynamic (QI) (Gori, Lotz & Nuhrenberg
> 1994), (2) quasi-axisymmetric (QA) and (3) quasi-helically symmetric
> (QH) ones (Boozer 2015). In these configurations, termed omnigenous,
> the second (or longitudinal) adiabatic invariant, J, is a function of
> the toroidal magnetic flux only, J = J(ψ), which can be shown to lead
> to confined guiding-centre orbits (Helander 2014). The difference
> between the three cases lies mainly in the way that the contours of
> constant magnetic field strength |B| close when plotted on magnetic
> flux surfaces: in QI they close poloidally, in QA toroidally and in QH
> helically. Additionally, while QA and QH belong to the class of
> quasi-symmetric stellarators, where all contours of |B| are straight
> in Boozer and Hamada coordinates (D’haeseleer et al. 1991), in QI only
> the contours of the maxima of |B| are required to be straight. All
> three types of configurations can be ‘directly constructed’ using the
> near-axis expansion, based on an approach using Boozer coordinates
> (Garren & Boozer 1991; Landreman, Sengupta & Plunk 2019; Plunk,
> Landreman & Helander 2019), while only quasi-symmetric stellarators
> have been obtained using an approach based on Mercier coordinates
> (Jorge, Sengupta & Landreman 2020b, a).
>
> The largest stellarator in
> operation, Wendelstein 7-X (Grieger et al. 1992), is of the QI type,
> though only very approximately given the fact that the magnetic field
> strength at local maxima and minima varies substantially over the flux
> surface, there is substantial neoclassical transport and losses of
> fast ions and the bootstrap current are non-negligible. This type of
> configuration is relatively insensitive to the plasma pressure since
> the Shafranov shift is small (Gori et al. 1994; Nührenberg et al.
> 1995; Cary & Shasharina 1997; Nührenberg 2010) and the bootstrap
> current vanishes identically at low collisionality (Helander &
> Nuhrenberg 2009; Helander, Geiger & Maaßberg 2011; Landreman & Catto
> 2012). Unlike quasi-symmetric configurations, QI ones may thus be
> operated with essentially no net toroidal current experimentally, even
> with finite plasma pressure.

The concept of omnigeneity is more or less clearly described in its Wikipedia [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omnigeneity):

> a magnetic field is called omnigenous if the path a single particle
> takes does not drift radially inwards or outwards on average.

Okay, got it.  I can imagine a particle trajectory with no net drift relative to the main axis of the plasma over sufficiently long times.

I also understand some aspects of the above explanations of QI, QA, and QH.  However I still feel that I am missing a basic visual or spatial intuition of how each of these configurations achieves the goal of no net radial drift.  Is there an easy picture or conceptual argument that illustrates this?

Comment: Just checking: are you OK with the basic concept of the SR in terms of net overall drift control due to "circulation" around the axis? That is, are you good with the basis of the original configurations?

Comment: I am not sure what SR means here, but I understand that in tokamaks we add a poloidal component, or "rotation," to the toroidal B-field so that particles spend an equal amount of time on the inside and outside of the torus, and thus ideally spend equal time drifting into and out of the plasma, resulting in no net drift.

Comment: In tokamaks, this poloidal component is achieved by inducing or otherwise driving a net current in the plasma itself.  However, in stellarators, the poloidal component is created by the configuration of the surrounding magnetic coils.  For example, in Spitzer's original design for the stellarator, the plasma had the shape of a figure-8, and by tracing particle trajectories, we can see how particles on the outside of one bend of the 8 are subsequently on the inside of the other bend and therefore ideally have no net drift.

Comment: Ok, I hope the following is answering your question...

Answer (score 1):

So the basic idea of the stellarator is to produce a magnetic field that results in the "lines of force" being shaped in such a way that the total path around the long axis is roughly equal in terms of being on the inside or outside of the center. As you note, the tokamak attempts the same but does so using currents in the plasma.

The original stellarator designs did this physically by rotating the entire tube around into a figure 8. But as the path is shorter on the inside of a curve, the cancellation is never perfect, the ions always spend more time on the outside and this leads to a net drift. Initially, it was believed the resulting drift would still be low enough to be useful Over time it was concluded that this was going to ruin confinement in any such design and work on the approach largely ended in the US and continued mostly in Germany and Japan.

The newer approaches ultimately attempt the same thing, but with newer configurations that address the "not entirely perfect" cancellation. They differ from each other primarily in the actual field configuration. Here is the best comparison I have found:

[image]

On the left is quasi-axisymmetric, the centre is quasi-omnigenous and the right is quasi-helical. The basic idea in all of these is to wind the entire plasma surface around the the center line, not just any one path. I think this is most obvious on the right side - follow the blue line for instance. As you can see, in this case, it really does spend the same amount of time on the inside and outside as the red line.

If you have a RG account you can [read the article here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/323271172_Stellarator_Research_Opportunities_A_Report_of_the_National_Stellarator_Coordinating_Committee).

From a confinement perspective, the quasi-helical (QH) design seems to be the best, as it has deep winding of the overall flow and the neo-classical transport is well controlled as a result. On the downside, it appears the resulting magnetic system is necessarily large and this results in large aspect ratios which are never ideal from an economical standpoint. (although, that said, the following image doesn't seem to be too bad in aspect ratio)

[image]

The quasi-omnigenous (QO) design (which your quote refers to as QI) is similar to QH in terms of confinement and has even lower neoclassical transport (and basically zero bootstrap) but is "less wound". This is the basis for W7-X, which is the best performing stellarator to date. It is somewhat simpler to arrange in terms of layout, but as one can see in images of that device, the magnets themselves are somewhat complex (ahem). Also note the very low aspect ratio here - that's a *whole lot* of magnets for an itty bitty amount of plasma.

[image]

Quasi-axisymmetric (QA) is most like a tokamak and there is a sort of continuum between toks with additional fields and pure QA designs. They have the simplest magnet layouts, but the drift cancellation is imperfect, so they theoretically have the worst confinement (whether that means anything in practice is a different question). Here you can see the individual magnets are somewhat simpler than those above, but use two different sets of magnets together to produce the ultimate shape.

[image]

All three designs have the same overall upsides compared to toks, the most important (IMHO) being self-centring within the field and little internal current so less/no issues with runaway electrons. They also have the same downsides, namely complex magnet systems, difficulty accessing the interior among the protein-like magnets, and in most cases, lower aspect ratios so more machine for less plasma.

Comment: This answer definitely receives an upvote from me for all of its ideas, but I am looking for a more precise mathematical or theoretical delineation of QI, QA, and QH.  For example, how do these three possibilities emerge as natural alternatives as we attempt to design configurations with no net drift?  Are they in some sense mutually exclusive and jointly comprehensive?  What is the technical motivation for Boozer coordinates?  So far, the best references I have found on these topics are Helander 2014 and Freidberg 2007, but the relevant parts of each are rather long.

Comment: Ahhh, well then I have bad news... Boozer's work is where it all starts, and getting solutions from it is about as easy as generating general solutions in GR.